# O que deve acontecer com uma reversão troll apenas para benefício próprio do OP?

Tags: suporte, histórico-de-revisões

Eu recentemente editei a publicação que estava mal indentada e sem formatação:
[Preloader com Materialize](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224758/preloader-com-materialize).

Essa edição foi aceita, porém há 3 horas atrás, houve uma reversão para a publicação original mal formatada, no qual me proporcionou *-2rep*. 
Alguns minutos depois, um outro usuário veio e re-intentou a publicação. Mesmo que fosse simples gosto do OP, fui em seu perfil e vi que ele tinha ganho o badge 'Limpeza'.

Aqui estão as revisões: [Revisões para Preloader com Materialize - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/224758/revisions).

Simplesmente o que aconteceu é que o OP retirou 2 de reputação minha, além de conseguir o badge, deu meus *+2rep* para outro usuário, e tudo isso sem motivo nenhum. Eu tenho direito de reverter novamente para minha edição, devo deixar do jeito que está e o caso não tem importância, ou o OP deve ser punido?

Comment: Eu nunca tinha feito uma reversão antes. Fui lá reverter para a sua revisão achando que assim ficaria você como o editor final, mas acabou ficando como sendo edição minha. Desculpe.

Comment: usuários acima com 2k+ não ganham pontos, esses +2 são apenas um incentivo para quem esta começando na comunidade. Sobre o AP, ele deve ter revertido pq simplesmente não entende que as edições são comunitárias, indique sempre o link do Help quando for assim, mantendo a educação, o Renan apenas restaurou para a sua edição que era o melhor, no geral esses +2 perdidos não só servem pra incentivar no começo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu acredito que o outro usuário que editou é inocente. A edição dele foi aprovada por outras pessoas, e acho que a maioria das pessoas que revisam edições não vêem o histórico completo.

Quanto ao autor da pergunta, eu assumiria ingenuidade primeiro. Ele cometeu um erro de formatação e não deve ter entendido a sua edição.

Não se sinta ofendido pelo que aconteceu, nem pelos pontos perdidos. Isso foi quase nada perto da sua reputação total. Apenas continue sua participação no site. Não vai demorar muito até você ter reputação para poder editar posts sem precisar de aprovação.